# Regarding German Patent attorney candidates

Tags: germany, patents, language

I'm thinking about becoming a German and European patent attorney.

I'm fluent in German (my mother language), English and French, (and Romanian, my other mother language).

The issue is that I have a certification in English only - C2.

I'm right now studying electronics engineering in German (not necessarily Germany), in Romania at the faculty of engineering in foreign languages in Romania.

I'm wondering, can I be a German patent attorney without a German official certification?

Comment: Do you mean an official German certification of your German-language competence?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: A quick google search regarding qualifications to start training is to have a university degree in engineering or natural sciences. I also see a practical technical job of 12 months duration before during or after university education. Then find an existing German patent attorney who will take you on as a trainee for three years and then take the test. I did not see any language certification mentioned.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks